# stat function call

Tags: c, stat

I want to use the `stat` function. But I don't know how to do it with variables. I get the value of DIRECTORY and sub-dir from some other process.

```
if( stat( DIRECTORY/sub-dir, &st ) == 0 )
{--}
```

I get an error message as follows `"error: invalid operands to binary /"`

Comment: Is DIRECTORY a define?

Comment: but, if don't know how to write a string literal or how to "`man`" a function, how far will you go in using properly the result?! sorry for the question: just curiousity.

Comment: Are `DIRECORY` and `sub-dir` variables? And if: How are they declared?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a single string and pass that to `stat()`.  Assuming VLA support (C99 or C11 with the relevant option available), then:

```
char path[strlen(DIRECTORY) + strlen(subdir) + sizeof("/")];
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", DIRECTORY, subdir);
struct stat st;
if (stat(path, &st) != 0)
    ...oops!...
else
    ...process data...
```

If you don't have VLA support, you can either use a fixed size array or `malloc()` and `free()`.

Either:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];  // Beware: not always defined; _POSIX_PATH_MAX?
```

Or:

```
size_t pathlen = strlen(DIRECTORY) + strlen(subdir) + sizeof("/");
char *path = malloc(pathlen);
if (path != 0)
{
    snprintf(path, pathlen, "%s/%s", DIRECTORY, subdir);
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) != 0)
        ...oops!...
    else
        ...process data...
    free(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
if( stat( "DIRECTORY/sub-dir", &st ) == 0 )
```

Refer to the [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) man page:

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

The first argument (the path) should be a `const char *` type so the path should be provided as string like `"DIRECTORY/sub-dir"`

if `DIRECTORY` and `sub_dir` are variables, then you have to concat them in a third variable:

```
char buf[256];
sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", DIRECTORY, sub_dir);
if( stat( buf, &st ) == 0 )
```

Comment: If DIRECTORY and sub_dir are variables, this won't do what the OP intends.

Comment: @MOHAMED And what if `DIRECTORY` and `sub_dir` are over 256 chars in total? Hint: `snprintf()` exists.

Comment: ... such as [Jonathan Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19663900/296974) wrote.